# Dimple.js: How to color the background of groups in a grouped bar chart?

Tags: javascript, css, dimple.js

Please refer to the screenshot:

[image: Grouped Bar Chart with background of each group colored grey]

I would like to know how I can color a group in a grouped bar chart with a background color.

I am aware `series.afterDraw` as shown in [Advanced Custom Styling Example here](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_custom_styling) can be a way to do such customization. But need help in identifying the coordinates that make up each group.

Or is there any other way I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get this done by:

1. calculating the max value of each group
2. draw a background chart with max values on y axis
3. overlay the grouped bar chart with original data on top of background chart

The code for the same is:

```
// Create the svg and set the dimensions
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 400, 400);

// Sample data for grouped bar chart
var data = [
    {id: 1, type: "t1", count: 10},
    {id: 1, type: "t2", count: 5},
    {id: 1, type: "t3", count: 6},
    {id: 2, type: "t1", count: 5},
    {id: 2, type: "t2", count: 7},
    {id: 2, type: "t3", count: 3}];

// Calculate maximum of each group.
// This will be the y axis value of background chart
var maximums = [{id: 1, max: 10}, {id: 2, max: 7}];

// Create background chart
var chart1 = new dimple.chart(svg, maximums);
var x1 = chart1.addCategoryAxis("x", "id");
var y1 = chart1.addMeasureAxis("y", "max");
chart1.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
chart1.defaultColors = [new dimple.color("#D3D3D3")];
chart1.draw();
// Remove axis titles of the background chart
x1.titleShape.remove();
y1.titleShape.remove();

// Overlay the actual chart on top of background chart
var chart2 = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart2.addCategoryAxis("x", ["id", "type"]);
chart2.addMeasureAxis("y", "count");
chart2.addSeries("type", dimple.plot.bar);
chart2.draw();
```

Following is the screenshot of the chart:
[image: Grouped Bar Chart With Background Highlight]

[Fiddle for the same is available here](http://jsfiddle.net/nagarajanchinnasamy/2j8pgz8k/2/)